# Clarifying Return 0 and 1

Tags: c++, c, return

So returning **0** in a function **(Not main)** means **false** and returning **1** or anything but **0** means **success**.

Why in the main() function do we put **0**, meaning there were no errors when **1** in other functions mean it ran successfully, thanks.

Comment: You seem to be mixing the notions of "success Boolean" and "error code". Some functions return `true` on success and `false` on failure (and sometimes additionally set a global variable like `errno` to some error number); others (like `main`) return an error code, with `0` meaning "none" (i.e. "no error", i.e. "success") and non-zero numbers corresponding to various errors.

Comment: Your premise, that returning 0 would mean false and returning 1 would mean true is... misguided. Rest of the question does not make much sense after that.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`0` and `1` (or any non-zero number) convert to the boolean values `false` and `true` in a context where a conversion to `bool` happens, e.g. in `if(`*`here`*`) ...`. This is used *within* your program.

The return value from `main` is used in a different way, it is returned to the shell that called the program. In the shell's context the value is interpreted differently. There, `0` traditionally means "no error" while values larger than zero indicate errors and the value itself contains some hints as to what kind of error occurred. Take this snippet from `man grep`:

```
EXIT STATUS
     The grep utility exits with one of the following values:

     0     One or more lines were selected.
     1     No lines were selected.
     >1    An error occurred.
```

Comment: This clarified additional questions I was going to ask, thank you.

Comment: You might consider using exit(EXIT_SUCCESS) and exit(EXIT_FAILURE) to avoid complications in the interpretation at least from your point. As @DanielFrey stated it really depends on the tool that receives the exit code of your application but you can't do anything about that.

Answer (score 9):

Returning a certain number does not mean anything by default.

The developer decides what a method returns and what the returned value means.

`main` returns an exit code and `0` for *no error* which is kind of straight forward and there are a lot more possible return values that just `0` and `1`.

Answer (score 2):

There is no standard on which value represents failure and which represents success. However, traditionlly, C/C++/Unix choose to use 0 as success and non-zero for failure, because the non-zero value can be used as error code to represent a variety of failure reasons.

Answer (score 2):

Think of it this way:

By tradition, no function ever returns a boolean indicating success. Instead, the return type is either some error number or some object pointer.

Now, if an error code is returned and no error occurs, naturally no error is returned. This is the meaning of zero when `main()` returns. Consequently, `if(main())` means something like `if(error)`.

Likewise, if an object pointer is returned, and an error occurs, no object can be returned, which again is indicated by zero (= a null pointer). So, `if(getObject())` means something like `if(/*getObject() actually returned something*/)`.

So, even though it looks the wrong way round, it is not. It's just that nothing ever directly returns a success boolean.

Answer (score 0):

Returned value for itself means nothing, developers decide if that value means error or not.

But take a look at error codes and their handling.

```
int MyFunctionWhichCanFail(...)
{
    /*some code*/
    return ERROR_CODE;
}

int FunctionWhichWorksWithFunctionWhichCanFail()
{
    if (MyFunctionWhichCanFail(...))
    {
        //some error handling
    }

    //other stuff
}
```

In this case it is possible to occur many different errors, so error code is very good option, in cases there possible result failure/success is better use `bool`.

Also I want to note, that in most systems zero is defined as `ERROR_SUCCESS` (or some other keyword which means success).